# How to fetch filtered data from a pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm going to register an ambassador. Ambassadors have relationships with users. So I have a pivot table;

When I go to register an ambassador, I bring the data of a user and they are shown in a select. However, I can only show those users that were not registered as ambassadors or that are not in the ambassadors_users table.

I tried to do something like this but it duplicates the data.

```
$users = DB::table('ambassadors_users');
$users = $users->join('users', 'ambassadors_users.user_id', '!=', 'users.id');
$users = $users->get();
```

Comment: Why are you using "literal" queries instead of relationships? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: But is there an eloquent / method that can identify this? I tried to do it that way, because I don't know how to do it. Hence my question.

Comment: What is the difference between for a user to be registered as a ambassador and being in the ambassadors_users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Eloquent Relationships, can use `whereHas()`; it will helps you to check the users has ambassadors or not.

By the way below query may helps you-

`$user_ids = DB::table('ambassadors_users')->pluck('user_id', 'user_id')->toArray();`

**Users those are not in ambassadors_users table-**

$users = DB::table('users')->whereNotIn('id', $user_ids)->get();

**Users those are in ambassadors_users table-**

`$users = DB::table('users');`

`$users = $users->join('ambassadors_users', 'users.id', 'ambassadors_users.user_id');`

`$users = $users->get();`

Or, `$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $user_ids)->get();`

Comment: In whereNotIn, I have to pass the column. At least in the version I'm using. However, it gives the following error. `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake. I have edited my answer. It should be `whereNotIn('id', $user_ids)`;
At first, make sure `$user_ids` gives you a collection (array) of id or not.

Comment: The way you get the data from the `ambassadors_users` table, it doesn't work because they come with a key and only the value. So I did it like this: `$user_ids = DB::table('ambassadors_users')->pluck('user_id', 'user_id')->toArray();`. corrected in answer